# SQL Subquery Return Null if no data found matching condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying the run the below query, but I am getting an error when the subquery is trying to return a value where the conditions don't exist.

Can someone please advise the easiest way to force a default return value if the where condition on the subquery returns blank.

I am getting an error where I am using a date where no data was recorded and it's giving me an error and exiting.

I'm trying to obtain the data for some R analysis.

use Runtime

```
SELECT ah1.DateTime,ah1.Value as TPH,
(select value
from dbo.AnalogHistory
where tagname = 'CR_CR001_SPEED.PVAI'
and datetime = ah1.DateTime
) as CR_SPEED,

(select value
from dbo.AnalogHistory
where tagname = 'CR_CR001_MOTOR_I.PVAI'
and datetime = ah1.DateTime
) as EM_Current,

(select value
from dbo.AnalogHistory
where tagname = 'CR_TE741023G.PVAI'
and datetime = ah1.DateTime
) as EM_NDE,

(select value
from dbo.AnalogHistory
where tagname = 'CR_TE741023H.PVAI'
and datetime = ah1.DateTime
) as EM_DE

  FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogHistory] ah1
  where TagName = 'CR_WQI752010.PVAI'
  and wwResolution = '600000'
  and DateTime > '20160816'
  and wwRetrievalMode = 'cyclic'
```

Comment: If your issue is that you have no result set because the `DateTime > '20160816'` returns no results, you're going to have to use a `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE <insert conditions>) BEGIN ... (my query if results exist) ... END ELSE BEGIN ... (my query if no result set) ... END`

Comment: Hi ZLK, The other query returns the data as expected in 10min intervals and runs for about 20secs and then crashes with a data not found error on CR_TE741023H not found due to the date correlation. It's to do with a period of time when data was not collected due to comms issues.

Comment: What error do you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't really need all those `correlated subqueries`.  Here's another option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select DateTime, 
       max(case when TagName = 'CR_WQI752010.PVAI' then Value end) as TPH,
       max(case when TagName = 'CR_CR001_SPEED.PVAI' then Value end) as CR_SPEED,
       max(case when TagName = 'CR_CR001_MOTOR_I.PVAI' then Value end) as EM_Current,
       max(case when TagName = 'CR_TE741023G.PVAI' then Value end) as EM_NDE,
       max(case when TagName = 'CR_TE741023H.PVAI' then Value end) as EM_DE
from [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogHistory] 
where TagName in ('CR_WQI752010.PVAI', 'CR_CR001_SPEED.PVAI', 'CR_CR001_MOTOR_I.PVAI', 
                  'CR_TE741023G.PVAI', 'CR_TE741023H.PVAI')
      and DateTime > '20160816'
group by DateTime
having max(case when TagName = 'CR_WQI752010.PVAI' then wwResolution end) = '600000' and 
       max(case when TagName = 'CR_WQI752010.PVAI' then wwRetrievalMode end) = 'cyclic'
```